# Detect Oculus Passthrough changes in Android app

Tags: oculus, oculusquest

I am running an Android app in the Oculus Quest 2 and would like to trigger actions based on events from the Oculus. Like exiting or entering the Boundary created by the user.
Is there any way this can be achieved? With intent filters?